# Conditionally import script files

Tags: javascript, html

In the  tag I want to conditionally import some  tags depending on whether a parameter has been set in the url.

Currently I have:

```js
function getURLValues(name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (results == null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return results[1] || 0;
  }
}

if ((getURLValues('dev') == "true")) { <
  script src = "localhost:4200/gamefiles/TitleCard.js" > < /script>
} else { <
  script src = "TitleCard.js" > < /script>
}
```

But I'm not sure how or even possible to print the script tags out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.createElement()` and `document.body.append()` to include the script. Note that the scripts will start running AFTER everything in the body loads.

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script")
if ((getURLValues('dev') == "true")) {
  newScript.src = "localhost:4200/gamefiles/TitleCard.js"
} else {
  newScript.src = "TitleCard.js"
}
document.body.append(newScript);
```

To add multiple scripts at once, you can use `element.insertAdjacentHTML();` and ternaries if you need:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<script src='" + (getURLValues('dev') == "true" ? "localhost:4200/gamefiles/TitleCard.js" : "TitleCard.js") + "'></script><script src='" + condition ? "script1.js" : "script2.js" + "'></script>");
```

I have used `"afterbegin"` for the position. See [more options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#parameters)

Comment: Thanks :) I have a large number of js scripts to do this for (like 16) is there a more automated way I could do that? Also will these scripts only be appended to the body now rather than the head?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward I have added a faster way to add multiple scripts. That's to my knowledge's extent. Yes, these scripts will be added to the body. However, the second option includes an option to add to the top of the body rather than the end. It will most likely load/run faster when it's at the top.